# How to prevent row stretching vertically in a grid?

Tags: asp.net, grid, height, row

I have following code. When there is more than 1 row, it displays the rows with correct height. However, once there is only ONE row left, it's height stretches to the whole grid.
Can anybody tell me how I can get the normal height for the single row? Thanks a lot.

The code:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="100">
<Grid Name="dataSetGrid2">
<Grid.RowDefinitions></Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Is it a specific height you're looking for, or should the height still change based on the content inside?

Answer (score 1):

This may help you figure why it happens like that.
[Christian Moser's Blog](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)

The most useful part for you would be the "Define Rows and Columns" section.

> **Fixed**     Fixed size of logical units (1/96 inch)
>
> **Auto**  Takes as much space as needed by the contained control
>
> **Star (`*`)**    Takes as much space as available (after filling all auto and fixed sized columns), proportionally divided over all star-sized columns. So 3*/5* means the same as 30*/50*. Remember that star-sizing does not work if the grid size is calculated based on its content.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```